# Problema conexión local (MongoDB)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy realizando un bootcamp de programación y al abordar el apartado de las noSQL db no han parado de aparecerme errores.

Tras conseguir por fin poder trabajar desde el MongoDB Shell y crear una pequeña base de datos llamada "blog", al intentar conectar la web ejemplo con la base de datos en el servidor local (localhost:3000), no hay manera de establecer la conexión. El error es el siguiente:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lunavel\DAW_DAM\100daysbootcamp\connecting nosql with nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:312       
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lunavel\DAW_DAM\100daysbootcamp\connecting nosql with nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:312:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:568:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:510:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 168302287,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lunavel\DAW_DAM\100daysbootcamp\connecting nosql with nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:380:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Lunavel\DAW_DAM\100daysbootcamp\connecting nosql with nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:300:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}

Node.js v17.3.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

He vuelto a crear la base de datos desde 0 y he repetido los pasos del profesor 4 veces asegurándome que todo el código sea exactamente igual al de él y no hay manera, agradecería un montón si alguien que haya tenido el mismo problema y lo haya solucionado pudiera ayudarme!

Muchas gracias!!

El código es el siguiente:

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

let database;

async function connect() {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  database = client.db("blog");
}

function getDb() {
  if (!database) {
    throw { message: "Database connection not established!" };
  }
  return database;
}

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase: connect,
  getDb: getDb,
};
```

```
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");

const blogRoutes = require("./routes/blog");

const db = require("./data/database");

const app = express();

// Activate EJS view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Parse incoming request bodies
app.use(express.static("public")); // Serve static files (e.g. CSS files)

app.use(blogRoutes);

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  // Default error handling function
  // Will become active whenever any route / middleware crashes
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).render("500");
});

db.connectToDatabase().then(function () {
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Comment: Como estás configurando mongo? La verdad es que no tendrías que configurar nada si solo estás probando, normalmente todo está listo en default.

Comment: Puedes revisar varias cosas, tu instancia de mongo está corriendo en el puerto default? o algo mas lo está ocupando? Puedes conectar por compass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por cierto ahora que me fijo, estas en node 17, por alguna razón en esta versión de node, mongo resuelve el `localhost` a la dirección IPV6, si te fijas en el error marca que no puede acceder a `::1:27017` por lo que la solución mas fácil seria reemplazar `mongodb://localhost:27017` con `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017` que es la interface que usa mongo por defecto.

La solución ideal seria ver el por que en node17 `localhost` resuelve a una ipv6, por lo menos con mongo, y cambiarlo claro.

Por otro lado no es muy difícil acostumbrarse a utilizar `127.0.0.1` en lugar de `localhost`, ¿por que no?

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: No es necesario cambiar `localhost` por `127.0.0.1`, basta con usar la propiedad `family` en las [opciones de conexión](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/#connection-options) y establecer la misma a `4` (por IPv4). Saludos

Comment: Es indiferente realmente, de una manera u otra las dos ocupan una cantidad similar de caracteres para una sola conexión, realmente en general usar 127.0.0.1 siempre es mas correcto que localhost.

Comment: Finalmente conseguí que funcionara!! reemplazando el código con el mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 y borrando el caché se conectó! Muchas gracias :)